# Can anyone tell me what I have planted?

Tags: identification, houseplants, vegetables, indoors

I have a feeling it could be beetroot but not totally sure.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Or it could be chili

Comment: It's very difficult to identify a seedling before it grows normal leaves. The first couple of leaves are "seed leaves" and they look quite similar in many species of plants. Once your plant has its next pair of leaves, please post a picture of them.

Comment: Definitely not beetroot. I was thinking some type of chilli or capsicum/pepper, so if that is a possibility, then I suspect the answer is chilli.

Comment: Many thanks I'm also guessing it's chilli as remember planting some can't wait for these to grow